# Getting Unexpected Result in Python in Multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, math, multiplication

**I Made a program to multiply two large numbers but did,nt get expected result**

When I Use My Program Result("**1131231231231231232132176453243264237453265745327432747324575342321321321324234234324234243242343213**","**3242342342342342343243212341234**")

I Got 3667838920001082329580291288441145791080382201626879559138562006502209700363203527339095217292763913228365618564468855268114011142

But When I Directly multiply these numbers in python i get
**1131231231231231232132176453243264237453265745327432747324575342321321321324234234324234243242343213 * 3242342342342342343243212341234**

3667838920001082167184590525973693204469083965208483826796404950051845708090751087384204216926015556670850912511772595077899944842

**Both are Different.**

```
def Result(val1,val2):
    array = []
    offset = "1"
    for x in range(len(val1)-1,-1,-1):
        result = MultiplyTwoNum(val1[x], val2)
        result = MultiplyTwoNum(offset, result)
        offset = MultiplyTwoNum("10", offset)
        array.append(result)
        #print(result)
    return array
def MultiplyTwoNum(VAL1,VAL2):
    Val1Int = int(VAL1)
    #print(Val1Int)
    ValResult = ""
    ValCarry = 0
    FinalResult = ""
    for i in range(len(VAL2)-1,-1,-1):
        Val2Int = int(VAL2[i])
        ValResult = (Val1Int * Val2Int)+ValCarry
        ValLeftValue = ValResult%10
        ValCarry = int(ValResult/10)
        FinalResult = str(ValLeftValue) + FinalResult
        if i == 0:
            FinalResult = str(ValCarry) + FinalResult
    return FinalResult
num = Result(Num1,Num2)
r = 0
for i in num:
  r = r + num
print(r)
```

Comment: Assuming that Python is right and you're wrong will be correct about 99.999% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This innocent-looking expression:

```
int(ValResult/10)
```

Is wrong.

Judging by the `int()` around the division, you already know that division between two integers yields a float in Python 3. But putting `int()` around it doesn't work, it's too late, the damage has been done: `ValResult` has already been converted to a float, potentially rounding it. It's a solution that seems to work when tested with small values (which do not get rounded when converted to a float), but it does not hold up under serious use.

Use integer division:

```
ValResult // 10
```

If I make that change in your code, the right result comes out, at least for the specific numbers in the question.

---

Perhaps it was intended that `ValResult` would always be small, in which case `int(ValResult/10)` is somewhat reasonable (but you may as well write `ValResult // 10` anyway). However, it does not work out like that. `ValResult` indeed *can* be a large number, due to `MultiplyTwoNum(offset, result)`, where `offset` may be a large power of ten.